# Report Builder 1.0 vs 2.0. Search function disappeared?

Tags: sql-server, reportbuilder, report-builder2.0

We have a client who is migrating from Report Builder 1.0 to Report Builder 2.0. Yes, I realise they are very behind the game, and RB3 has been out ages, but there are internal reasons why they are making this decision ...

This being the position we are at, there is a "search" button on RB1, that doesn't exist on RB2.

[image: Report builder 1.0 search button]

It allows the user to search for fields in the database at report design time.

Does anyone have any thoughts on if/where the same feature exists in RB2? My suspicion is that the functionality is somehow part of Report Models in RB1 and so obviously doesnt exist in RB2.

Many thanks,

Marcus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. thanks to the two guys that posted suggestions ... I have found a work around, not exactly what I was after, but it has satisfied the particular user concerned. It is as follows:

It has been discovered that the “Search” functionality is linked (for some reason) to the “Cube Models”, A “Report Model” needs to be generated from the cube/sql source within the Report manager (e.g. http://ServerName/ReportServerName/)

[image: Build Report Model]

Then in RB2.0 (or RB3.0) create a new data source connection

[image: New Data Source Connection]

Then “Add Dataset” on the data source created, choose “Query Designer”, then desired perspective, then the “Search” function will be available.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this will help you, but it seems from these instructions you can run a search option once you preview a report:

http://blogs.msdn.com/blogfiles/crm/WindowsLiveWriter/ReportsforCRM4.0usingSQLServer2008andR.0_A800/sid08_2.jpg

Comment: thanks for the thought @Novazero, but I'm wanting to run the search to search for fields in the database while designing the report instead of at report run time ...

Answer (score 0):

I believe that Report Builder V 1.0 was created to be ad-hoc friendly in that this feature was designed with the paradigm of a user not knowing what they are wanting to use at design time.  In other words, that the user had no other way of looking up entities.

With V 2.0, a different approach was taken obviously and it assumes the creator can query for that information and so the feature was dropped or just simply not brought over to 2.0.

F1 help on both versions demonstrates the "dropping" of this feature and looking around Microsoft MSDN seems to back up that assessment (eq feature notes are dropped in 2.0 documentation).

I could be wrong here but that is my understanding.

I hope that helps.